# Importing a python file from another directory but in same parent

Tags: python

I have this strucutre:

`app/src/main.py`

`app/test/test.py`

I want to import a function from main.py to test.py

I tried adding `__init__.py` to the parent lib and also the directories but it gave me an error.

the error is:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: How (from which directory and by what command) are you running the `test.py` file?

Comment: I am running it with `python3 test.py` from the directiory init

Comment: In the structure you showed there is no `init` directory

Comment: No I mean the folder that the test.py is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
sys.path.append('../src/')
import src.main as mainfn
    
mainfn.function()
```

change `function()` with the name of your function